# Flutter Android APK for some devices is missing MaterialLocations

Tags: android, flutter

I just build my app via `flutter build apk` and send the `app-release.apk` to a discord channel of a friend. We both downloaded and installed the APK. On my device everything looks as expected but on this device there is a rendering issue.

We have the same device - the `Samsung A52` with Android 12 and One UI 4.1.

Here is a screenshot of mine:

[image]

And there the screenshot from his device:

[image: ![enter image description here]

For some reason there is a grey box rendered on his device. The same happens on a secondary device he has.

I also use different emulators and it looks fine on those.
I have no idea what is going wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not render issue. This is the error widget showing. In release error widget wont have the red box! This might be some layout issue. please provide code for more info.

Comment: How can it be an layout issue on two identical devices?

Comment: @Vettiyanakan I just gave my friend the normal apk and now we can see the error output. However I am still confused about the issue!

Comment: I just figured out that this can be something with localizations. I am using localization libraries for the form builder library. I am using an english device, why my friend is using a german one.